# if range("a1").value is blank then copy range("a2") or give me a msgbox that values are blank i don't know where i am wrong

Tags: vba

```
Sub If_Test1()

If Range("a1").Value = " " Then
   Range("a2").Select

ElseIf Range("a2").Value <> "" Then
       Range("a2").Copy

Else

MsgBox "C9 & E9 are Blank please check"


End If


End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

Thank you myself

Sub Test1()

If Worksheets("sheet1").Cells(1, 1).Value = "" Then

Worksheets("sheet1").Cells(2, 1).Copy

Else: Range("a1").Copy

End If
Range("D3").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues

Activeselection = False

End Sub

Answer (score 0):

1. Put "" except " " in condition as `If Range("a1").Value = "" Then Range("a2").Select` because " " doesn't mean a blank cell
2. except `If Range("a1").Value = "" Then Range("a2").Select` I'd prefer  `If Len(Range("a1"))>0 Then Range("a2").Select`
3. Also you can use `If IsEmpty(Range("A1")) = True Then Range("A2").Select`